# Best practices for a daemon that forks and becomes user

Tags: python, linux, networking

I want to write a small daemon in python under Linux that accepts connections and authenticates the user (details for this don't matter) and then forks a child for the connection and becomes the user. I will probably even want to start a whole new python program for dealing with the users connection from then on (passing the socket as stdin/stdout?).

Now my question is: What are the best practices for the forking and becoming the user? My question is about how to handle login records (utmp, wtmp), pam, and whatever other things the child should do when becoming the user. And all of that in python.

Comment: Don't do it.  Every significant program that does this has caused remote-escalation-to-root vulnerabilities.

Comment: And you think that to keep running as root and executing command and scripts from the user as root is a better solution?

Comment: No, I think **starting out** as the user is a better solution.  So, for example, instead of homebrewing a daemonization technique, rather launch the user's instance from something like inetd, xinetd, or tcpserver.

Answer (score 0):

The basic stuff has to do with closing unneeded file handles, checking over signal handling and setting the proper user and group, as well as the daemonization process itself (attaching to init). On Linux systems or where possible in addition to setting uid and gid, there's setting a session id so that the process might be more easily found.

There is a [python daemonize module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonize/2.2.1) that I'd consult for what things to consider, if not use the module itself. (I've not used it, so I don't know firsthand its usefulness).

Comment: I'm not sure you are talking about the right thing. The daemon is already running and daemonized and everything and is talking to authenticated GUI clients. I'm now tasked with adding a new feature where a user can open a terminal to run commands or scripts and for that I want to fork a child that becomes the user and runs things.

Comment: Now I am totally confused. You write "I want to write a small deamon..." and the title is about "Best practices for a deamon", but somehow you now say this is about adding a feature to an exisiting deamon?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit unclear. I'm already writing said daemon for some time and it has other functions beside the forking to become a user. It's just the new part about becoming a user that are the problem. PS: I'm already using the python daemonize module.

Comment: I still don't have a clue as to what you are having problems with. I suggest rewriting your question making it less unclear.